# code sign cmd change App's shortcut by original file on Mavericks 10.9

Tags: java, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I was signing java app with embedded jre 1.7.21 on 10.8 and that was working fine.
When I moved to 10.8 to Mavericks 10.9 with XCode 5.0.2 - I am getting issue. My app is not getting signed.
Cause :  While building the mySample.app, copying jre to the .app in plugin folder.
here   MacOS Folder has a alias of file named - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/MacOS/**libjli.dylib**
is converted in to original file after signing step. App is getting signed but app not launch.

Is it Java 1.7.21 issue ? Because I read somewhere that Apple is not supporting the java Version 1.7.25 and below.

Is it Java Issue or Code Sign Issue on Mavericks ?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the java version 1.7.45 and then tried to signed. Now I am able to sign app as well as launch successfully...

It might be the issue with java version 1.7.25 and below version on mevericks+xCode 5.0.2